# Apollo not fetching updated results after mutation

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-client

I have a component who fetches user details by GetPersonQuery, now it's child component mutates the academic info of the user detail by CreatePersonAcademicExperience. 
And when I'm making the query run again, either by emitting a refresh event or toggling back and forth different components, I'm not getting the updated result in my GetPersonQuery

I get the fresh result only when I reload the browser

Here is where I fetch the query

```
this.apollo.query({
  query: GetPersonQuery,
  variables: {
    id: id
  }
 })
 .map(res => res.data)
 .subscribe((data: any) => {
   const person = data.getPerson
  })
```

Here is the mutation

```
this.apollo.mutate({
  mutation: CreatePersonAcademicExperience,
  variables: {
    id: this.currentUserData.id,
          academic_experience: data
  }
 }).subscribe(res => {
     console.log("res is: ", res)
   })
```